# D3D11 WARNING when combine D3D11 with D2D1

Tags: c++, directx-11

im trying to combine D3D11 with D2D1, all is work good but,
I get that warning every `swapChain->Present` call.
I found example here [D2D + D3D11 help me to make them work together](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/639578-d2d-d3d11-help-me-to-make-them-work-together/5038418/?page=1)

Why do i get that warning, and how to fix?

```
DXGI WARNING: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: Blt-model swap effects (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD and DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL) are legacy swap effects that are predominantly superceded by their flip-model counterparts (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL and DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD). Please consider updating your application to leverage flip-model swap effects to benefit from modern presentation enhancements. More information is available at http://aka.ms/dxgiflipmodel. [ MISCELLANEOUS WARNING #294: ]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSGetViewports: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IAGetInputLayout: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IAGetPrimitiveTopology: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IAGetVertexBuffers: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSGetViewports: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSGetViewports: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSGetState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMGetRenderTargets: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMGetBlendState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMGetDepthStencilState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::VSGetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::GSGetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSGetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSGetShaderResources: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSGetSamplers: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetInputLayout: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetPrimitiveTopology: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetVertexBuffers: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSSetViewports: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSSetState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetRenderTargets: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetBlendState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetDepthStencilState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::VSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::GSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSSetSamplers: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSSetShaderResources: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::Draw: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetInputLayout: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetPrimitiveTopology: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::IASetVertexBuffers: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSSetViewports: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::RSSetState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetRenderTargets: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetBlendState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::OMSetDepthStencilState: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::VSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::GSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D10Device::PSSetShader: This ID3D10Device[1] method of the immediate context is locked out because an ID3D11Device[1] device context state is active. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #3145945: DEVICE_LOCKEDOUT_INTERFACE]
```

also i tired that but it's not work nothing get rendered

```cpp
// create the D3D11 texture

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc = {};
texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
texDesc.Width = 512;
texDesc.Height = 512;
texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
ID3D11Texture2D *texture;
device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &texture);

// create D2D render target using texture

ID2D1RenderTarget *renderTarget;
IDXGISurface1* dxgiSurface;
texture->QueryInterface<IDXGISurface1>(&dxgiSurface);
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED));
factory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(dxgiSurface, &props, &renderTarget);
dxgiSurface->Release();
```

Comment: You seem to be using really outdated features, any reason for that? Why not use the newer `CreateSwapChainForHwnd`/`CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow`, `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL`, `ID2D1DeviceContext`...

Comment: i use ImGUI, and my project require multi drawer using same d3d11 device, So i use D3D11 as a graphic API, then use it with D2D1 and ImGUI.

Comment: Can't say with the code, please provide a minimal reproducible sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: minimal example already provided in the thread i mentioned https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/639578-d2d-d3d11-help-me-to-make-them-work-together/5038418/?page=1

Comment: The first warning has a link explaining what it's about. It's unrelated to your use of Direct2D. See http://aka.ms/dxgiflipmodel